# clustering of singular value

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

let us consider following graph of singular values

[image]

i want to make  some kind of  clustering of these data,namely to  seperate  main components from non main components,let say signal components from noise components,i would like to do like this(any software matlab,etc is great,better matlab)let us start like this  ,first do linear regression  with first point,then do regression analysis with first two point and so on,point is that  one want to  create two group,in first group   coefficients of  regression lines should be  close to each other, also in another group  regression coefficients should be close to each other,but regression  coefficients  in one group must be highly different then coefficients in another group,that means that we should find such point which separate this group optimally,  in other word i should stop regression analysis at some point which  well separate  two group,and another regression will start after this stop point till other rest points,please help me how to do it programaticaly

Comment: Have you tried [`smooth`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html)? Have you tried [outlier removal](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/curvefit/removing-outliers.html)? You seem to have a pretty good idea of what you want; did you try it yourself?

Comment: no not yet,i am expecting advice's  first,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plots shown are cumulative plots - clustering of these values may be significantly easier if you consider their individual values, not their cumulative values.

We can suggest many different clustering algorithms for these values, but with only one sample it is difficult to determine what methods will be most successful.
Some questions to consider are:

- Do you know how any clusters you want?
- Do you know absolute thresholds for these clusters?
- Will the values always be arranged into these groups of similar values?

Clustering is highly dependent on the behavior of the data over the larger dataset that you would like to be clustering within.

Finally, without knowing the *purpose* of the data, we are not able to comment on appropriate segmentations of this data that would yield good results for your application. In some cases, the first singular value may be enough, while in others, throwing away any of the eigenvectors in your transformation could be detrimental.

Comment: thanks for  help,let us consider first of all their  cumulative clustering,transform it to individual is easy,just  more points we would have,so  how can i do it int matlab?